# How to handle only one observer and dont call others?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the following usage of rxjs streams:

```
ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest(
        this.eventsService.subjectSearchDistribution.pipe(
            tap((querySearch) => {
                this.paginationService.setQuery(querySearch);
                this.paginationService.reset();
            }),
        ),
        this.eventsService.subjectSortingDistribution.pipe(
            tap((sortedList: ListItem[]) => {
                this.paginationService.setSortBy(getSortingString(sortedList));
            }),
        ),
        this.eventsService.subjectFilterDistribution.pipe(
            tap((filterUrl) => {
                const page = 1;
                this.paginationService.setFilterBy(filterUrl);
                this.paginationService.setCurrentPage(page);
                this.paginationService.calculateOffsetLimit(page);
            }),
        ),
        this.eventsService.subjectFilterDistributionReset.pipe(tap(() => this.paginationService.reset())),
    ).subscribe(() => {
        this.loadPage();
    });
}
```

Problem is I need to handle only one case, onle one stream and dont call others, as  result call `this.loadPage();`.

Now when I send message to `this.eventsService.subjectSearchDistribution`, `this.eventsService.subjectSortingDistribution`, `this.eventsService.subjectFilterDistribution`.

I see that calling of  `this.loadPage();` increases from fist time +1 each event.

SO, ONLY one observer can be active, not all torgether.

How to fix it?

Comment: did you try ngOnInit() for calling loadPage method instead calling from constructor?

Comment: Sure I call it in `ngOnInit() ` the same problem, because first time it calls loadPage from ngOnInit and the second time I get data from event where second time called

Comment: You could use a variable outside of the function that acts as a gateway. That once the function is called, it won't do anything anymore.

Comment: Why do you need the `.subscribe((res) => this.loadPage()` lines if the only thing you do is call `loadPage`? If you only want to call `loadPage` once, having the first line in the `constructor` should be enough. Can't you just remove the two `subscribe` lines without consequence? The only thing you do is call `loadPage` more.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I did not get you

Comment: Because when I get subscribe(res) I fill object pagination by res, then inside loadPage I use object pagination

Comment: As @3limin4t0r said, remove the subscriptions and call `this.loadPage()` in your constructor, basically `constructor() { this.loadPage(); }`, thats it.

Comment: I need subscriptions because form them I get propertis that uses by loadPage().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using rxjs:

```
ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest(
        this.eventsService.subjectSearchDistribution.pipe(
            tap((querySearch) => {
                this.paginationService.setQuery(querySearch);
                this.paginationService.reset();
            }),
        ),
        this.eventsService.subjectSortingDistribution.pipe(
            tap((sortedList: ListItem[]) => {
                this.paginationService.setSortBy(getSortingString(sortedList));
            }),
        ),
        this.eventsService.subjectFilterDistribution.pipe(
            tap((filterUrl) => {
                const page = 1;
                this.paginationService.setFilterBy(filterUrl);
                this.paginationService.setCurrentPage(page);
                this.paginationService.calculateOffsetLimit(page);
            }),
        ),
        this.eventsService.subjectFilterDistributionReset.pipe(tap(() => this.paginationService.reset())),
    )
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.loadPage();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the reason your `loadPage` method is called twice due to your event listeners, but without sharing the code for those methods I cannot confirm that issue. The simplest way to fix your double call of the `loadPage` method would be this:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.pageLoadCalled = false;
    this.loadPage();
    this.events.filter.listen().subscribe((res) => this.loadPage());
    this.events.search.listen().subscribe((res) => this.loadPage());
  }

  loadPage() {
    if (this.pageLoadCalled) {
      // Exit early (will not call anything below the return)
      return;
    }
    // Mark this method as being called
    this.pageLoadCalled = true;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      // do stuff
      resolve();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `loadPage() {}` methos it is request to server, I can use flag as you suggested, but maybe wrap this method to promise? Because two events are promises too. Then somehow manage them?

Comment: I've updated my example to include a promise. If you want the `loadPage` method to be always called until the promise resolves, then move the `pageLoadCalled` method inside the body of the `Promise`.

Comment: looks like a stitch. what about rxjs?

Comment: I've not used rxjs so I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `loadPage` only once, don't execute it when `events.filter` and `events.search` trigger:

```
class A {
   constructor() {
      // Call pageLoad in the constructor only once
      this.loadPage();

      // Remove call to pageLoad when events fire.
      // this.events.filter.listen().subscribe((res) => this.loadPage());
      // this.events.search.listen().subscribe((res) => this.loadPage());
  }
}
```

Comment: I need events, because they returns me parameters that I use in loadPage(), when event comes it has filter parameters that I pass to pagination server. Then i loadPage() I use paginationService with filled properties

Comment: Yes but you already called `loadPage` when these events fired. From what you want and what the code look like, I think your architecture has to change

Comment: How does `loadPage` uses data from `events.filter` and `events.search` events?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217834/discussion-between-coverbase-and-baboo).

Comment: Lets go to chat

Comment: I have posted message to chat

Comment: I have updated question with my attemps, it was unclear for many